# ERROR: 'ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation' despite having same versions of DB in client and server

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, roracle

I am trying to connect to a remote Oracle DB using ROracle from the client side.

After establishing connection, I execute this query:

```
dat = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM TABLE_01")
```

This leads to the error:

> Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
>     Error in try({ : ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation

I checked the DB version in server side:

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION

PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Then I ran genezi in client side:

```
    genezi -v

System name:    Linux
Release:        4.4.0-36-generic
Version:        #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016
Machine:        x86_64

Operating in Instant Client mode.
Small timezone file = timezone_14.dat
Large timezone file = timezlrg_14.dat
```

The Oracle version of both client and server is 11.2. But the timezone file seems to be different. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when I ran my Ruby on Rails app in a docker container.  (The error did not happen when running the app outside the container.)

I needed to remove this line from my Dockerfile:

```
ENV TZ America/New_York
```

And these lines from config/application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

That seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have different timezones installed between the database server and the client.

To check the database version:

```
select * from v$timezone_file;
```

To check the client version:

```
genezi -v
```

(Which you've done already - your client is on 14. I suspect the database is using a more recent version).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the error "ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation issue" with a client after upgrading the database from 11g to 19C.
Upgraded the client as well but the error remained unsolved.

The workaround was to copy $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo contents into the same directory on the Client side. (not sure if this is supported though, but I will verify)